# Connect to remote system through socket

Tags: java, sockets

Am trying to connect to a remote system which is not in the same local area as mine through java sockets, can anyone share some sample code or docs to do so.

I have created a server socket and is listening for connection at a port.how can i connect to that socket from my client program that is not in the same local area network as the server.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you ping the server from the client?

Comment: Should i be using th ip address of the server as the ip address provided by the ipconfig command.?

Comment: yes i cant ping the server , it says unreachable

Comment: If it is unreachable then forget about sockets. Use USB or e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html provides both server and client examples of connecting to a socket.

Comment: What should be the host in the client side code. socket = new Socket("kq6py", 4321);
"kq6py"=?

Comment: "kq6py" is the name of the computer.  You could put an IP or a FQDN (www.example.com) in there  and it would work.  (Assuming that there's a path through the firewall, of course.  If it can't get in through the firewall, then it just won't work.)