# Java connect 2 PC in different networks

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create a connection between 2 softwares using java sockets. 
In particular: 
 - The first is a server that can have n clients
 - The second is the client

When the client connection I send the IP of the client. 
When something happens, the server selects the correct ip and opens a connection to send some data.

If I use InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() I send to the server the local IP, so it will work only if the programs are in the same network. 
If I use external services like:

```
     URL url = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
      String IP = input.readLine();
```

It won't work if I don't set a port forwarding on the router.

The committee asked me to make the simplest thing from the user point of view, so I cannot ask to every user that will have the program client to set the port forwarding on the router etc.

Is there any solution to enstablish this type of communication?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help at all or have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922136/connect-to-remote-system-through-socket

Comment: It could be a good idea to retrieve the socket connection 
but my problem is before this step, when I have to enstablish the connection :(

Comment: I know this is tricky and you don't want to handle this yourself. There should be libraries out there to handle this for you.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243437/java-tcp-ip-server-client-communication-over-the-internet

Comment: Here there is the solution with the router ports configuration. 
I think that this will be the unique solution that :(